# Plot a heat map on a google map with 3d data in R

Tags: r, google-maps, heatmap

I've created a table of data which has a series of `Lat/Lon` coordinates and a corresponding number from 0-100+ I'm looking to somehow overlay this onto a google map and create a heatmap from it but all I can find are methods which concern 2d data i.e. coords but no corresponding factor.

I've been quite stuck on this for a while so if anyone knows of any functions that might do the trick or would like to have a crack at it let me know and I can post some code/data.

Simplified data

```
Lat Lon Value
26  -72 0
26  -73 1
26  -74 2
26  -75 3
26  -76 2
26  -77 1
26  -78 0
25  -72 0
25  -73 0
25  -74 1
25  -75 2
25  -76 1
25  -77 0
25  -78 0
24  -72 0
24  -73 0
24  -74 0
24  -75 1
24  -76 0
24  -77 0
24  -78 0
27  -72 0
27  -73 0
27  -74 1
27  -75 2
27  -76 1
27  -77 0
27  -78 0
28  -72 0
28  -73 0
28  -74 0
28  -75 1
28  -76 0
28  -77 0
28  -78 0
```

Somehting like [this picture](https://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/density-mapping-in-google-maps-with-heatmapapi/) would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by "somehow overlay this onto a google map"? What is your ultimate goal? (Maybe a picture would be nice) Exactly which methods did you look at so far, and what funcionality are they missing? In addition, please include a small example data set or a reproducible way to create one.

Comment: `library(ggmap)` will do the trick. See: http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions jhin, I've edited my question. the data didn't work so well though!

Comment: This looks like it's in development on the [leaflet package in R](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) if this [pull request](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/174/commits) is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Since I wrote my comment under the question, I've added this capability into my googleway package

To use Google Maps you need a valid Google Maps API key

```
library(googleway)

map_key <- "your_api_key"

google_map(key = map_key) %>%
    add_heatmap(data = df, weight = "Value", option_radius = 0.5)
```

[image]